# Solidity contract not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I'm having trouble running my first solidity contract in remix ethereum and through web3 so I'm guessing something is wrong with my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract cntrct 
{
  uint public aaa; 

  function() payable public
  {
    create(msg.value);
  }

  function create(uint _value) internal
  {
    require(_value>0);
    aaa = _value;
  }

  function reader() view public returns(uint)
  {
    return aaa;
  }
}
```

I succesfully deployed the contract in both remix and web3. However, after sending a transaction to the contract, the `aaa` variable is still `0`. What I want this code to do is update the `aaa` variable to the last deposited amount so I can read it later by calling the `reader` function. In remix it does not show any input field for the `aaa` variable. Also, in MetaMask transactions sent to the contract stay in a pending status even if they're already completed (balances updated in remix and tx in testRPC.)

In node I'm using the following line to try to execute the `reader` function but I'm unsure if this will work.

```
contract.methods.reader().call(0, (error, result) => { if(!error){console.log(result);}});
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s no reason to store the ether sent in a state variable unless you need to maintain a mapping of balances spread across multiple addresses. The total balance is held in the contract and is accessible with `this.balance`.

In addition, fallback functions are limited to 2300 gas. You can’t write to storage (ie, update a state variable) within that limit. Your variable isn’t updated because it’s failing. See the second bullet point [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In solidity contract, you can read the value of public filed by calling field as a method. here, `aaa()`

I have deployed with mist browser under private network and send 10 ether to this contract successfully.

[image: deployed contract with 10 ehter]